# For complex surfaces, is it true that quotient singualrities $=$ rational double points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity

Consider a complex surface $S$. An isolated singularity of $S$ is called a *rational double point* if it is locally analytically isomorphic to $(f^{-1}(0)\subset \Bbb C^3,0)$ where $f=f(x,y,z)$ is one of the following polynomials: $x^{k+1}+y^2+z^2 ~(k\geq 1), x^{k-1}+xy^2+z^2~(k\geq 4), x^3+y^4+z^2, x^3+xy^3+z^2, x^3+y^5+z^2$.

An isolated singularity of $S$ is called a *quotient singularity* if it is locally analytically isomorphic to $(\Bbb C^2/G,0)$ where $G$ is a finite subgroup of $\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)$.

According to Theorem A of the paper "Fifteen characterizations of rational double points and simple critical points" by Durfee (link: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.474.1363&rep=rep1&type=pdf), a rational double point is a quotient singularity and conversely (Characterizations A1 and A5 in the paper).

Also, in chapter A.3 in the paper, it says that rational double points has the following property: the exceptional curves in the minimal resolution are rational curves with square -2.

On the other hand, for example in this link: [https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/blog/cyclic1.html](https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahjde/blog/cyclic1.html), there is a different result of the minimal resolution of a (cyclic) quotient singularity.

What went wrong?

Comment: Rational double points are the same as quotient singularities $\mathbb C^2/G$ where  $G$ is a finite subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ (not $GL(2,\mathbb C)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with asking $G$ to be a subgroup of $GL(2,\Bbb C)$. The correct definition in order to get the Du Val singularities (what you're talking about in the first portion of the problem) is that $G$ should be a subgroup of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ - you'll note that in general, the matrices defining the group action in the second link are not in $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ and only in $GL(2,\Bbb C)$.

Comment: Thanks. Then is the paper I've mentioned has an error?

Comment: If it says $GL$ instead of $SL$, yes!

Comment: To be more explicit about the error, which seems to be in the claimed implication A5 -> A2, I believe one would need to add the assumption in A5 that the variety is a hypersurface, as that is implicit in A2, but not in A5, and it is also not implied by A5 as far as I can tell.